# Pandas Filter on date for quarterly ends

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

In the index column I have a list of dates:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-12-31', '2011-01-02', '2011-01-03', '2011-01-29',
           '2011-02-26', '2011-02-28', '2011-03-26', '2011-03-31',
           '2011-04-01', '2011-04-03',
           ...
           '2016-02-27', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-26', '2016-03-31',
           '2016-04-01', '2016-04-03', '2016-04-30', '2016-05-31',
           '2016-06-30', '2016-07-02'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=123, freq=None)
```

However I want to filter out all those which the month and day equal to 12/31, 3/31, 6/30, 9/30 to get the value at the end of the quarter.

Is there a good way of going about this?

Comment: does `df.loc[df.index.is_quarter_end]` work?

Comment: So your text is a little contradictory, are you asking you want the end of quarter values or you want to filter those entries out, so you want all row values apart from quarter end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`is_quarter_end`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.is_quarter_end.html#pandas.Series.dt.is_quarter_end) to filter the row labels:

```
In [151]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(400,1), index= pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2016,1,1), periods=400))
df.loc[df.index.is_quarter_end]

Out[151]:
                   0
2016-03-31 -0.474125
2016-06-30  0.931780
2016-09-30 -0.281271
2016-12-31  0.325521
```

Comment: genius! so simple as well.